# Iterating through object in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I want to iterate through following json and create a dynamic form,. But, both its key and value are not same. So how do I iterate it in JS?

```css
["register_form",
   {  
      "name":{  
         "fielde":"textfield",
         "description":""
      },
      "pass":{  
         "pass1":{  
            "field":"password"
         },
         "pass2":{  
            "field_type":"password"
         }
      },
      "mail":{  
         "field":"textfield",
         "description":""
      },
      "field_first_name":{  
         "field_type":"textfield",
         "description":""
      }
      
   }
]
```

none of these working:

```css
//Get the size of object = no. of fileds to be created
var size = Object.keys(response[1]).length; 
console.log("Size..." + size);

console.log("Keys.." + Object.keys(response[1]));
var keys = [];
var model = [];
var label = [];
keys.push(Object.keys(response[1]));

for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
   angular.forEach(response[1].keys[i], function(key, value){
   console.log(key + "..." + value);            
});
```

Comment: Have you tried for..in loop to iterate through object?

Comment: I did it, but unable to fetch both key and its value. e,g,: I want to fetch "name" and its value - another obj with field and description as keys and resp values of it

Comment: how many fields need to be created, 5? Your data keys are not consistent.. You have ( field, fielde, field_type ). Are they typos?
You also have nested objects inside "pass", is that intentional as well?

Comment: yes, its intentional

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Vanilla javascript like this:

```
for (key in response[1]){
console.log(key)
};
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94o2v2v0/)

Comment: don't forget about `.hasOwnProperty()` check

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $sce){
$scope.user = {};
  $scope.register_form = {"name":{  
                         "field_type":"text",
                         "description":""
                      },
                      "pass1":{ 
                            "field_type":"password"
                       },
                       "pass2":{ 
                            "field_type":"password"
                       },
                      "mail":{  
                         "field_type":"text",
                         "description":""
                      },
                      "field_first_name":{  
                         "field_type":"text",
                         "description":""
                      } };
  $scope.formData = { name : "" };
  $scope.html = "";
  angular.forEach($scope.register_form, function(value, key){
    $scope.html = $scope.html + "<input type="+ value.field_type +" placeholder="+key+" >";
   });
  $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form>
    <div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml">
    </div>
  </form>  
</div>
```

Comment: I want to iterate in controller not html/tempalte

Comment: What is the need to iterate in the controller?

Comment: i wnat to create a dynamic form, for which i am using - https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

I think this is what you need. You can format the output whatever way you want.

```js
var data = {  
      "name":{  
         "fielde":"textfield",
         "description":""
      },
      "pass":{  
         "pass1":{  
            "field":"password"
         },
         "pass2":{  
            "field_type":"password"
         }
      },
      "mail":{  
         "field":"textfield",
         "description":""
      },
      "field_first_name":{  
         "field_type":"textfield",
         "description":""
      }
   };
function toArray(obj) {
    var result = [];var passName;var tempArray = [];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        var value = obj[prop];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
                $('#myForm').append("<br/><b>[[" + prop +"]]</b><br/>");

            if ($.isNumeric(prop)) {
                passName = name + "[" + prop + "]";
            } else {
                passName = name + "['" + prop + "']";
            }
            tempArray = toArray(value, passName);
            $.each(tempArray, function (key, value) {
                result.push(value);
            });
        } else {
        $('#myForm').append("<label>" + prop +"</label> : <span>" + obj[prop] + "</span><br/>");
            result.push(name + "['" + prop + "']");
        }
    }
    return result;
}

toArray(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myForm">

</div>
```

Comment: var arr = Object.keys(response).map(function(k) {  response[k] }); tried this too, no much help!